# Rewrite to lang parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm really bad at htaccess, I can't figure this out.

I have the following file:

```
/site/.htaccess
```

I would like to create a rewrite that would rewrite:

```
/site/en/home/
```

to:

```
/site/home/?lang=en
```

and (`var` is just an example, it should work with any query string):

```
/site/en/home/?var=12345
```

to:

```
/site/home/?var=12345&lang=en
```

How can I accomplish this? I've been at it for 1 hour and I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in /site/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^en/(.+)/?$ /site/$1/?lang=en [QSA,L]
```

QSA QueryStringAppand flag automatically appends the addtional queryString to the target.

Comment: Thanks. How can I grab "/home",so that I don't have yo add directories manually in the htaccess?

Comment: @nbrogi You can grab that using regex capture group **(.+)** and use the captured part using **$1** backrefrence. See the updated rule.